# Dynamically updating TabWidget icons?

Tags: android, tabwidget, tabactivity

Is it possible to update the TabWidget icons/indicators? If so, how, when you are creating TabContent through intents?

Edits below with answer thanks to @Bart

Generic code:

MainActivity:

```
public class TestActivity extends TabActivity {

public int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(
            new Intent(this, OneActivity.class)).setIndicator("One"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(
            new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class)).setIndicator("Two"));

    changeTitle(0, 20);
}

public void changeTitle(int cnt, int i){
    View v = getTabWidget().getChildAt(cnt);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setText("One ("+i+")");
}
```

}

OneActivity (ChildActivity):

```
public class OneActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i = Integer.parseInt((String) tv.getText());
            i++;
            tv.setText(""+i);

             TestActivity parent = OneActivity.this.getParent();
             parent.changeTitle(0,i);

        }
    });
}
```

}

I'd like to show the number in the Tab's title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but it is a bit of tricky:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0);
TextView tv = (TextView) vg.getChildAt(1);
```

You should pay attention to indices while calling getChildAt(). The best way is always to debug and check.

Since 1.6 TabWidget has a method getChildTabViewAt thanks to which you could skip the first line and write:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0);
```

---

I attach also source code of Android SDK to show how TabWidget icons are built:

```
View tabIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, 
mTabWidget, // tab widget is the parent
false); // no inflate params

final TextView tv = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
tv.setText(mLabel);
final ImageView iconView = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
iconView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
```

As you can see, it contains a TextView and ImageView.

Comment: Note that your "source code of Android SDK" is for some specific version, and that code may change, and so you do not want to rely upon that implementation.

Comment: How do I pass the value from OneActivity to MainActivity (extends TabActivity)?

Comment: I agree that using getChildAt() may not work on every SDK. I wrote that it is tricky. It will work for sure in versions from 1.6-2.1 since I tested it.

@Sameer Segal: you can get a reference to MainActivity from OneActivity by calling TabActivity mainActivity = (TabActivity) oneActivity.getParent();

Comment: I think I am missing a step here. I've updated the code on top and am not able to find a function OneActivity.getParent().

Comment: Figured it out -- thanks Bart! Updated my question with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try get the imageView like this

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)tabActivity.getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.icon);

v.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newIcon));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a arrays for titles and icons

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++ ) {
    TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec(String.valueOf(i)); //sets tab index
    Drawable icon = res.getDrawable(icons[i]);  //sets the icon
    // set tab text and icon
    spec.setIndicator(titles[i], icon);  //sets the title

    host.addTab(spec);
}
```